# How do I delete contact suggestions from Messages in OS X?

Tags: macos, messages

In the "To:" box in the Messages app on OS X, when I start typing in a contact name, I get old "iMessage" contacts which I've long since deleted. They certainly don't exist in my contacts; the only place I think they could exist is in my iMessage History somewhere on the iCloud servers. In any case, how can I delete them? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't there an i next to their name?

Comment: @Rob: Nope... afraid not. Just the text "iMessage". Some names/numbers also have a chat bubble toward the right of the dropdown, but not all (in particular the ones I want to delete).

Comment: Are you sure they're in no address list which has been connected to your account?

Comment: @Rob: Yep, 100% sure. It seems to be something stored/cached by iMessage, annoyingly.

Comment: How in the world has this not been fixed yet? I have a contact where I used to just be able to type there name but for some time now it's been autocompleting to an *invalid* address

Comment: @Sirens: Apple don't seem to care about "minor" bugs like this. I reported it on their official portal years ago, but nothing!

Comment: In the suggestion, if it says `Siri found in apps` then go to System Preferences > Siri > Privacy > Uncheck the app(s) and test again. This happens in Sierra / High Sierra

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/152124/38539) provided by @Noldorin works for me:

> Messages on OS X doesn't allow "Recent" contacts to be deleted, but
>   Messages on iOS does allow this. An oversight by Apple, but this is a
>   fix nonetheless.

To clarify, I looked at recent addresses on my iPhone/iMessage when starting a new conversation. There's an "i" symbol which allows your to see recent group conversations and addresses, and also a remove button.

Once removed the erroneous address is no longer visible in OS X iMessage.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution myself: Messages on OS X doesn't allow "Recent" contacts to be deleted, but Messages on iOS *does* allow this. An oversight by Apple, but this is a fix nonetheless.

Comment: Not really a fix.  It's removed from iOS but it still shows up in OS X.

Comment: @MarqueIV: Not true at all; it is removed from both, since the data is stored in iCloud!

Comment: Actually, what you stated isn't true because I have two iPads, an iPhone 6 and my mac, all syncing their contacts through iCloud, and even though I successfully deleted the contact (which propagated the delete), then manually did the 'Remove from Recents' on all iDevices (where it now no longer shows up) it *does* still show up on the Mac. I deleted the contact weeks ago.

Comment: @MarqueIV: Looks like you have a problem with your account then, because I have three Apple devices, and it works just fine. I suggest you ring up Apple and complain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the person in iMessage on iOS device (when typing the name of the person that should not be in your contacts anymore, that person's name may still appear. press the little "i" icon on the right and choose "remove from recent"), Quit and reopen imessage on OS X, when you start typing that name it will no longer show. It syncs from the iOS device

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution 
i submitted it here , but was refused

un check all the boxes in application messages general
[image: un check all the boxes in application messages general]

Sorry : wrong picture ,should have uploaded a screenshot of picture containing entry rudy
[image: send a message and click delete]

take an entry and send a message

[image: take an entry and send a message]

the following message will appear, if you delete the converation

[image: the following message will appear]

entry rudy will be gone

[image: entry rudy will be gone]

Comment: there might be a problem if on your iPhone the setting is keep forever the messages . may be set this to 30 days, Might also be related to the OS , this works in OS Sierra

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Go to settings, accounts and passwords, iCloud.
Then where it says “apps using iCloud” turn off contacts.